# running shell command

Tags: c#, wpf

my application will run a command that is like this:

wco -f "C:\Work\6.70 Ex\Master Build.Txt"

what i do is i usually open up cmd and type the above line manually.

i tried to automate this with a script:

```
            string strCmdText = "wco -f C:\Work\6.70 ex\Master Build.Txt";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

however because of the white spaces it gets confusing.
please help

Comment: try `"wco -f ""C:\Work\6.70 ex\Master Build.Txt"""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your arguments just like you do on the command line plus you need to escape your backslashes:

```
string strCmdText = "wco -f \"C:\\Work\\6.70 ex\\Master Build.Txt\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cmd.exe to run a program, you need to add either the `/C` or `/K` switch. The /C switch runs the command and then exits cmd.exe. /K runs the command and then leaves cmd.exe open.

```
cmd.exe /K echo hello
```

I assume `wco` is a program of yours? If so, you can bypass using cmd.exe and just call wco.exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the escape character, which is `\` in C#.

```
string strCmdText = "wco -f \"C:\Work\6.70 ex\Master Build.Txt\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

However, if "wco" is an executable, the actual code you should use is

```
string strCmdText = "-f \"C:\Work\6.70 ex\Master Build.Txt\"";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wco", strCmdText);
```

This will probably make it easier to redirect the output.